# Prime ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Am I right that all prime ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ has the form $p\mathbb{Z}[x]$ for some prime $p\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hint: they can't be all the primes since none of them are maximal (since modding out by them yields the non-field $\Bbb Z_p[x])$

Answer (score 10):

No, this is not right. There are much more prime ideals. They come in two flavours:

1. Principal ideals $(f)$, where $f$ is either zero, a rational prime, or an irreducible polynomial.
2. Maximal ideals are of the form $(p,f)$, where $p$ is a rational prime, and $f$ is an irreducible polynomial which remains irreducible modulo $p$.

Graphically, here is a ["picture"](http://matrix.cmi.ua.ac.be/DATA2/GrothMumford.jpg) of $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb Z[X])$.

Comment: What are the coordinate axes $0,1,2,...,\infty$ in the lower right corner supposed to mean ($\mathbb Z[X]$ has dimension 2) ? And what has $\overline {\mathbb Q}$ got to do here?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg I don't know. I was looking for the picture from Mumford's *Red Book* and thought the one above was similar enough. I didn't notice at first the axes in the corner. Maybe someone else will be able to answer.

Comment: Dear M Turgeon: so apparently someone xeroxed Mumford's drawing and added  a few  strange notations. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some, for example: $\langle 0 \rangle$ and $\langle x \rangle$ since the quotient is an integral domain