# Fiber of a map between spectra

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Consider the integral domain $A:=\mathbb Z \left [\sqrt {-3} \right]$ and its integral closure (in $\mathbb Q \left [\sqrt{-3} \right ]$) that is $\bar A=\mathbb Z \left [\frac{1+ \sqrt{-3}}{2} \right]$. I must find the fiber of the morphism $\operatorname {Spec} \bar A\to\operatorname {Spec} A$.

If I consider the morphism $$A\hookrightarrow \frac {A[x]}{2x-1-\sqrt{-3}},$$ for a prime $\mathfrak p\in \operatorname{Spec} A$ its preimage consists of the ideals generated (in $A[x]$) by $\mathfrak p$ and $f(x):=2x-1-\sqrt{-3}$, and eventually by other polynomials in $A[x]$ *that are not congruent modulo an element of $A$ to a polynomial in $(f(x))$*. Do these polynomials exist? Can I describe them better?

The sentence in italics should be justified with the fact that if a polynomial $g(x)$ is congruent to $f(x)$ modulo an element of $\mathfrak p$, it belongs already to $(f(x),\mathfrak p)$; while if $g(x)$ is congruent to $f(x)$ modulo an element of $A\setminus \mathfrak p$ then $(\mathfrak p ,f(x),g(x))=A[x]$.

EDIT: I thought of this solution that seems reasonable, where basically I used for every fiber that the prime ideals of $\frac{\mathbb Z \left [\sqrt{-3} \right ][x]}{2x-1-\sqrt{-3}}$ containing $(p)$ for a prime $p\in \mathbb Z \left [\sqrt{-3} \right ]$ are in bijection with the prime ideals of $\frac{\mathbb F_p[\sqrt{-3}][x]}{2x-1-\sqrt{-3}}$, except for the fiber over $(0)$ where I used the analogue argument but for localizations. I also used that in general $A[x]/(a_1x-a_2)\cong A$ if $a_1$ is invertible.

The fiber over $(0)$ is $\operatorname{Spec}\left(\mathbb Q \left [\sqrt{-3} \right ]\right)$; over $(2)$ is $\operatorname{Spec}\left(\mathbb F_2[x]\right)$, because $2x-1-\sqrt{-3}$ is the zero polynomial in $\mathbb F_2[x]$; over $(\sqrt{-3})$ is $\operatorname{Spec}\left(\mathbb F_3\right)$; for the other primes $(p)$ the fiber is $\operatorname{Spec}\left(\mathbb F_p \left [\sqrt{-3} \right ]\right)$. Two precisations: $\operatorname{Spec}\left(\mathbb F_2[x]\right)$ is just two points plus the generic point? And for the other fibers, since I'm always obtaining fields, the spectra is a point (so the map induces a bijection), regardless of $\mathbb F_p$ containing a square root of $-3$ or not, right?

Comment: Do you know what the conductor of an order in a number field is? Can you find it here?

Comment: Actually we didn't see it in the course

Comment: Maybe you can look at what happens to $X\to \overline{X}$ over the each point of $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$. In particular you should notice that away from $(2)$ this is an isomorphism.

Comment: Now above $(2)$ show that the map is of the for $\mathbb{F}_4\to \mathbb{F}_2\oplus \mathbb{F}_2$ mapping $1$ to $(1, 1)$.

Comment: Sorry I have been thinking for a while but I can't get your suggestion

Comment: If you denote $S=\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$, then your morphism $X\to \overline{X}$ is an $S$ morphism, to study it fibers you may study the fiber of $X_s\to \overline{X}_s$ where $s$ is any point of $S$. If you take $s\neq (2)$ then $X_s\to \overline{X}_s$ is an isomorphism, and $X_{(2)}\to \overline{X}_{(2)}$ is the map I defined in my previous message.

Comment: Yes the idea is clear, I meant that I can't see why the situation is different for $(2)$ (it seemed an isomorphism to me)

Comment: Well, there are several way to see it, but for instance using the description you gave of the map $A\to A[X]/ax+b$ if $a$ is invertible, it's clearly an isomorphism, but what if $a$ isnt'? Tensor with $\mathbb{F}_2$ and you can study that map over $(2)$. Maybe giving a description of $A\otimes \mathbb{F}_2$ would help (and is easy to find).

Comment: @Ahr I made an edit to the post, with a solution that seems similar to yours (I don't understand well tensor products so I can't tell if they are the same). Could you tell me if it's ok ? Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit confused by the argument that you made in your edit... I would dissuade you from trying to work with "nested" objects like $\mathbb{Z} \left [\sqrt{-3} \right ][x]$ unless absolutely necessary, because (at least for me) they're much trickier to reason about than classical polynomials. It sounds like you have the right general idea, but you might be a bit confused on the details. In particular it *does* matter what happens to $x^2 + 3$ mod $p$ for various $p$ when it comes to computing prime ideals. It only doesn't matter for this problem because we're interested in how the prime ideals in $A$ *compare* to those in $\overline{A}$.

To try to clear things up, I'll try to be fairly detailed in how you might attack this problem. Moreover,
since you mention you aren't familiar with tensor products as a means of getting at the fibres, I'll include a more pedestrian approach. I can't help but try and explain why the tensor product "trick" works, though, so you'll have to forgive a quick digression.

With that out of the way, on with the show ^_^.

---

First, what *are* the (nonzero) primes in $A$? Well, if we write $A = \frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{x^2 + 3}$, then we see the prime ideals in $A$ are exactly the prime ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ that contain $x^2 + 3$. [We know](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221107/spectrum-of-mathbbzx) that these look like $(p,f)$ where $f$ is irreducible mod $p$, and so we're looking for ideals $(p,f)$ where $f \mid x^2 + 3$ (mod $p$). Of course, we'll *write* this polynomial $f$ as $f(\sqrt{-3})$ instead of $f(x)$ (since $x = \sqrt{-3}$ in our ring).

For example, let's compute the primes that lie over $(2) \in \mathbb{Z}$. That is, the primes where $p = 2$.

We want to know that

$$
\frac{A}{\left (2,f \left (\sqrt{-3} \right) \right )} 
\cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{(x^2+3,2,f)} 
\cong \frac{\mathbb{F}_2[x]}{(x^2 + 1, f)}
$$

is a field. Of course, the only way to do this is to choose $f = x+1$, which gives us the prime
$\left ( 2, \sqrt{-3}+1 \right)$.

Doing this for a few other primes, we can draw a quick picture of $\text{Spec}(A)$:

[image: a picture of spec(A)]

(If it's not clear why this is the spectrum, you should work these out in a way analogous to the example for $p=2$ above!)

---

Now, let's take a look at $\overline{A} = \frac{\mathbb{Z}[y]}{y^2 - y + 1}$. Again, elements of the spectrum will look like $(p,f)$ where $f$ is irreducible mod $p$, but now we want $f \mid y^2 - y + 1$ (mod $p$).

Again, let's look at the case $p=2$. Then we want

$$
\frac{\mathbb{Z}[y]}{(y^2 - y + 1, 2, f)}
\cong \frac{\mathbb{F}_2[y]}{(y^2 + y + 1, f)}
$$

to be a field. Of course, we know that $y^2 + y + 1$ is $\mathbb{F}_2$-irreducible, so $f = y^2 + y + 1$ is our only choice, and we see our prime ideal is just $(2)$ (notice we *don't* get $(2,f)$, because we already quotiented by $f$ in the passage from $\mathbb{Z}[y]$ to $\overline{A} = \frac{\mathbb{Z}[y]}{f}$!).

[image: spec(Abar)]

Notice the spectrum for $\overline{A}$ looks superficially similar to the spectrum of $A$ above every prime except $(2)$. We haven't worked out anything to do with the map $\text{Spec}(\overline{A}) \to \text{Spec}(A)$, but now we might have an intuitive plan for what we should look for algebraically!

---

Inspired by the geometry above, we're led to consider the primes above $(2)$ separately from the other primes. We can get at just the odd primes by localizing at the "function" $2$ (that is, by formally inverting $2$ by adjoining $\frac{1}{2}$).

So, we localize and the inclusion $A \to \overline{A}$ becomes the inclusion
$A \left [ \frac{1}{2} \right ] \to \overline{A} \left [ \frac{1}{2} \right ]$.

Of course, if we expand this out, we see we're looking at the map
$\mathbb{Z} \left [ \sqrt{-3}, \frac{1}{2} \right ] \to \mathbb{Z} \left [ \frac{1 + \sqrt{-3}}{2}, \frac{1}{2} \right ]$ which sends $\sqrt{-3} \mapsto \sqrt{-3} = 2 \frac{1 + \sqrt{-3}}{2} - 1$. This is easily seen to be an isomorphism, with inverse given by the map sending $\frac{1 + \sqrt{-3}}{2} \mapsto \frac{1 + \sqrt{-3}}{2} = \frac{1}{2} \left ( 1 + \sqrt{-3} \right )$.

In particular, since this is an isomorphism, it identifies the primes away from $(2)$.

All that's left is to consider what happens over $(2)$. Now, as has been mentioned a few times now, we *could* handle this case via fibre products. The idea here is that we can find the fibre over $\mathfrak{p}$ by considering the pullback (you should convince yourself of this):

[image: a pullback]

Of course, since the category of affine schemes is dual to the category of rings, we get a *pushout* of rings:

[image: a pushout]

This tells us that $f^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})$ should be
$\text{Spec} \left (\overline{A} \otimes_A A/\mathfrak{p} \right )$,
which is exactly what the comments and the other answer suggest.

---

It seems like you're looking for an approach that avoids this machinery, though, so let's see another way to do this.

The fibre over $\left ( 2, 1 + \sqrt{-3} \right )$ in $\text{Spec}(A)$ will be exactly the primes in $\text{Spec}(\overline{A})$ which pull back to $\left ( 2, 1 + \sqrt{-3} \right )$ under the natural embedding $A \hookrightarrow \overline{A}$. Of course, there's only one prime that does the job: $(2)$.

But notice

$$
\mathbb{F}_2 
\cong \frac{A}{\left ( 2, 1 + \sqrt{-3} \right )}
\hookrightarrow
\frac{\overline{A}}{(2)}
\cong \mathbb{F}_4
$$

is *not* an isomorphism!

So taking spectra, we find the fibre is $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{F}_4) \to \text{Spec}(\mathbb{F}_2)$, which is a bijection, but not an isomorphism.

At the end of the day, we see every fibre is a singleton, and we get an isomorphism of over every prime except $(2)$.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thank you for all your effort, I've just read your answer and surely I was supposed to do the exercise like that. I just don't understand a thing: how do you deduce that over $ (2)$  the induced map is not an isomorphism? Does it hold that $\operatorname {Spec} R\to \operatorname {Spec} S$ is an isomorphism only if $S\to R$ is an isomorphism in general?

Comment: Also, since your point of view is practically the same of my course (in the second and fourth paragraph of your answer, not the third), could you suggest me a book or another source for other similar exercises?

Comment: To your first comment, yes. $\text{Spec}$ gives an equivalence of categories $\mathsf{Ring}^\text{op} \equiv \text{AffSchm}$, and in particular it preserves and reflects isomorphisms. Notice that this is quite subtle! Even though the topological spaces for $\mathbb{F}_2$ and $\mathbb{F}_4$ are the same (they're both one point) the _scheme_ structure is different! (They have different structure sheafs).

Comment: To your second comment, unfortunately I don't know of a great reference for examples worked out like this... Eisenbud and Harris's _The Geometry of Schemes_ has a great section on morphisms and fibres, which you might like, as well as an entire _chapter_ on examples (with a subsection on arithmetic examples in particular), though they freely use tensor products to compute the fibre (as almost everyone does).

Comment: As another example of needing to be careful, look at the fibre of $\text{Spec}(A) \to \text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ over $(2)$. As a _set_, this has one point (which we identify with the prime $(2, 1 + \sqrt{-3})$), but as a _scheme_ we find it's $\frac{\mathbb{F}_2[x]}{(x+1)^2}$, which has one (nonreduced) point, and is $2$ dimensional as a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_2$. So somehow the scheme structure of the fibre remembers more information than just the underlying set.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the sequence of ring maps $\Bbb Z\to \Bbb Z[\sqrt{-3}] \to \Bbb Z[\frac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}]$. This gives a corresponding sequence of maps of spectra $\def\Spec{\operatorname{Spec}}\Spec \Bbb Z[\frac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}] \to \Spec \Bbb Z[\sqrt{-3}] \to \Spec \Bbb Z$. Over the open set $D(2)$ the first map of spectra is an isomorphism because it's the map $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-3},\frac12]\to\Bbb Z[\frac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2},\frac12]$ on rings. This means the only possible funny business is happening over the point $(2)\in\Spec \Bbb Z$.

The fiber of the map over $(2)$ is given by tensoring everything with $\Bbb Z/2$, so our sequence of ring maps is $\Bbb Z/(2)\to \Bbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]/(2) \to \Bbb Z[\frac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}]/(2)$. Rewriting the latter two as quotients of polynomial rings will make it easier to see what's going on: $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]=\Bbb Z[t]/(t^2+3)$, while $\Bbb Z[\frac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}]=\Bbb Z[u]/(u^2-u+1)$ where the map between the two is by sending $t\mapsto 2u-1$. Modding out by 2 everywhere, our map turns in to $\Bbb F_2[t]/(t^2+1) \to \Bbb F_2[u]/(u^2-u+1)$ by $t\mapsto -1$.

The spectra of both of these rings are just single points since they're artinian local rings, but they're non-isomorphic: the former has nilpotents, while the latter is a field. So the map on spectra coming from normalization is a non-isomorphic bijection over $(2)$ and an isomorphism everywhere else.

Comment: I don't understand well your answer, but from what we covered in the course I should use an argument similar to the one in my edit. I don't understand where I'm wrong in the edit: the fiber over $(2)$ aren't the prime ideals of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt {-3}][x]/2x-1-\sqrt{-3}$ that contain (2)? I.e. $\mathbb F_2 [x]/2x-1-\sqrt{-3}$?

Comment: The tensor product is just packaging your argument in different language - it is exactly the sort of argument you're after. Secondly, your final sentence of that comment is just not right - you're making some wild errors because you're not converting things to a quotient of a polynomial ring by some ideal. For instance, you're quotienting by the ideal generated by $2x-1-\sqrt{-3}$: $2=0$, and what's $\sqrt{-3}$? If it's some element of $\Bbb F_2$, then you have either $\Bbb F_2$ or the zero ring, which is just wrong.